# Does Android Lint support analysis for a single file (xml, java)?

Tags: android, jenkins, continuous-integration, lint

I'm working in a project to perform verifications at submit change time through Gradle. Would it be possible to use Android lint for that?

For example, based on the changes of a specific commit, run a Lint analysis.

Let's suppose we would like to check the Manifest file, or even a Java class:

`> lint AndroidManifest.xml -check ...`

`> lint src/com/example/MyClass.java -check ...`

I'll really appreciate any support.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Android Studio supports it, which makes me think that `lint` should support it too... but I don't see how

Comment: @BenP. Indeed, after dig in to `lint`, I've checked support per-file linting. For example, if you are editing a single file in an IDE and you hit Ctrl-S, lint will rerun analysis on that single file. It means the Lint supports it, let's see if we can do that through CLI.